# Relative layout gradient mask android

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

Hi i'm now developing application that contain a profile like twitter profile 
I got a small problem . 
the problem is how to make a gradient black trasparent mask effect like this 
[image]

can anyone help me or provide me a code how to make this effect with xml please 
thank's :)

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: i design the profile but the probleme is when user make a cover in white color the name of profile and his pseudo  will not be displayed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I good understood you you should create new drawable xml as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
            android:startColor="#000000"
            android:centerColor="#C0C0C0"
            android:endColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:angle="90"/>
</shape>
```

And set it as background on your view.

Comment: I am glad that I could help you :)